# Write x^y using UTF-8

Tags: java, math, unicode

i was wondering how to write this mathematical operation x^y using the Unicode Transformation Format (**UTF**) in Java.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, *x^y*, that's in UTF8. Or did you want something more specific? Please elaborate.

Comment: What is your exact question? are you looking for the operator in Java for the exponentiation? there is none.

Comment: You are looking for `xʸ`? If so have a look in Wikipedia [unicode superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes i´m looking for this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small example code to print it on the console (if you see a `?` or a non-solid block character instead of `ʸ` your console is not able to print this character).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("x^y = x\u02b8");
}
```

**output**

```
x^y = xʸ
```

Instead of using the unicode value you can directly use

```
System.out.println("x^y = xʸ");
```

depends if this is supported by your used font and editor.

Comment: I see the question mark in my output "x?" That means, it´s not possible to display it like this "xʸ" in my case. Okay, I´ll use the simple notation x^y. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @chrisy No, that is not what that means. It means that you have correctly set the output encoding to UTF-8.